# Have JDK and JRE8 but still can't use switch with strings

Tags: java, switch-statement

Switch statements with strings were introduced in JDK 7 and I have JDK 8 and JRE 8 but when I attempt to use a switch statement with strings I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
>
> Cannot switch on a value of type String for source level below 1.7. Only convertible int values or enum variables are permitted

What should I do?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: what IDE do you use, if you use Netbeans in project properties set the JDK to 8

Comment: If you are working from command line, type `java -version` and let me know the output.  If you are using an IDE, some IDEs have 1.7+ syntax switched off by default, even if they are using a 1.7+ compiler.  If you are using an IDE please post which one.

Comment: If you are using Eclipse: go to project properties -> Java Compiler -> Compiler compliance level -> set to 1.7

Answer (score 0):

Which IDE are u using? I just give you some hint for Eclipse. Right click your project and found properties, switch to Java Compiler tab, make sure the compilation level is set to java 7 or above. 
I hope you are not using some last decade Eclipse because compilation level is bound to the Eclipse you use, not the JDK.